# Finding minimum value of my ArrayList of float values

Tags: java, arraylist, floating-point, min

I'm having all sorts of problems trying to do something that I expected to be quite simple. I have an ArrayList of float values, and I want to return the minimum value in the list as a float. I expected something like this to work:

```
public float getMin(){
float min = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(listOfThings)));
return min;
}
```

but I keep running into loads of incompatibility problems.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could describe one problem you are running into from the loads you have.

Comment: Your code will work correctly if listOfThings is a float array. So I don't understand why you would would get any problems here.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Collection as generic, `Collection.min` returns `Object` so you should convert it.

do this:

```
Object obj = Collections.min(arrayList);
Float f = Float.parseFloat(obj.toString());
return f.floatValue();
```

Or simply define `ArrayList` as

```
ArrayList<Float>
```

and you don't need to convert it.

Comment: No, it doesn't return `Object`: `Collections.min()` is typed. It returns the same type as the type of the collection.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java8 you can use stream object to achieve your goal:

```
float value = list.stream().min(Comparator.<Float>naturalOrder()).get();
```